# Does a php like checkdate() function exist in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In php there is a checkdate (month, day, year) function which helps in checking whether the date is a proper date or not. Does a similar function exist in JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

You could easily create your own one, but you have to know how Javascript handle's non-exisiting dates:

```
new Date(2010, 14, 34); // gives Sun Apr 03 2011, it just counts on.
```

So, this would do the trick:

```
function checkDate(year, month, day){
  var d = new Date(year, month, day);

  return d.getFullYear() == year && 
         d.getMonth() == month &&
         d.getDate() == day;
}
```

Comment: Or if you *really* want to go the PHP way, you can resort to phpjs.org's solution: http://phpjs.org/functions/checkdate:366